# why there's a difference of performance gain among both these queries?

Tags: sql, performance, select, between, rownum

> SELECT instmax,
>   r
>   FROM
>     (SELECT instmax,
>       rownum r
>     FROM
>       ( SELECT instmax FROM pswlinstmax ORDER BY instmax DESC NULLS LAST
>       )
>     WHERE rownum <= 10
>     )
>   WHERE r >=6;

## Output

[image]

> > SELECT instmax,
> >       r
> >     FROM
> >       (SELECT instmax,
> >         rownum r
> >       FROM
> >         ( SELECT instmax FROM pswlinstmax ORDER BY instmax DESC NULLS LAST
> >         )
> >        )
> >     WHERE r between 6 and 10;

## Output

[image]

Is there really a definite performance gain among both the query?Can you please clarify me on this?

Answer (score 1):

Oracle cannot push conditions that involve aliased `ROWNUM` into the inline views.

This means that the second query will use a full table (or index) scan with filtering on `rn`, while the first one will use `STOPKEY` (since it uses unaliased `ROWNUM < 10`)

You may want to read this article:

- [**Oracle: ROW_NUMBER vs ROWNUM**](http://explainextended.com/2009/05/06/oracle-row_number-vs-rownum/)

Comment: I am not able to open that link.Can you please  broaden your explanation?

Comment: @Pradosh: there is too much text there to copy it here. The link is working (just checked).

Answer (score 0):

That's probably because the STOPKEY optimization doesn't work anymore.

The "rownum < xx" is very special (called Top-N query) that has special optimizations. the between clause doesn't trigger that anymore.

You should compare the exeuction plans and look for "STOPKEY", if that is in, it is the optimized Top-N query.

see also:

http://blog.fatalmind.com/2010/07/30/analytic-top-n-queries/

Comment: what is actually this this STOPKEY optimisation? Can you explain me in a simplified way?

Comment: @Pradosh: this means the engine will stop the query after it fetched the `10th` record.

Comment: @Quassnoi.ok so in the 1st query it will fetch only till 10th row.ok

Comment: STOPKEY indicates that the database stops searching further values becuase the "rownum < x" expression has been reached.

without STOPKEY, the database searches all values, but filters out (in the next step) the ones not needed.